# $(this) / .each help: jQuery 404 check through YQL

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check a link (that I know if unavalable 50% of the time, but at random times) to see if it returns a 200 HTTP Status code. If so I want to change the class on the link from offline to online.

Desired process: get all links that point to ip addresses, give them class Offline, for each do a request to YQL, if a 200 code is received change class to Online.

Currently I have this:

```
var streams = $('article a[href^="http://65"]');
streams.addClass("offline");
streams.each(function (){
    destination = $(this).attr("href");
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=use%20%22store%3A%2F%2FtbYorcb2jIkiHPcRbkpSUG%22%20as%20HTTPStatus2%3B%20select%20status%20from%20HTTPStatus2%20where%20url%3D%22"+ encodeURIComponent(destination) +"%22&format=json&callback=",
        function(data){
            var httpstatus = data.query.results.result.status;
            if(httpstatus == 200){
                console.log('If = 200');
                changeStatus();
            }
        }
    );
    function changeStatus(){
        console.log('changeStatus called');
        $(this).removeClass("offline").addClass("online");
    };
    //$(this).removeClass("offline").addClass("online");
});
```

This all seems to work apart from the changeStatus function. I thought that by putting it outside the AJAX request in a seperate function it would work, but it doesn't. 
It looks like the problem is the `$(this)`  reference which isn't right. However if I put the same statement outside of a function (as commented out in the code above), it works fine.

Any help / pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: "this" has no meaning inside of the callback function. The callback event happens outside of the scope of your each loop.

Comment: Thanks Splash-X - I'd thought that was the case, but didn't know how to get around it (and couldn't have expressed it properly!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use $(this) inside of your changeStatus function, the this identifier refers to the changeStatus function object, not the current stream being iterated. You need to pass the object in, or move changeStatus into the other function.

```
streams.each(function (){
    var that = $(this),
        destination = that.attr("href");

    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=use%20%22store%3A%2F%2FtbYorcb2jIkiHPcRbkpSUG%22%20as%20HTTPStatus2%3B%20select%20status%20from%20HTTPStatus2%20where%20url%3D%22"+ encodeURIComponent(destination) +"%22&format=json&callback=",
        function(data){
            var httpstatus = data.query.results.result.status;
            if(httpstatus == 200){
                console.log('If = 200');
                changeStatus();
            }
        }
    );
    function changeStatus(){
        console.log('changeStatus called');
        that.removeClass("offline").addClass("online");
    };
});
```

You're also missing a "var" on your destination variable.

Edit: some help with the "this" keyword: http://jqfundamentals.com/#example-2.40

Comment: Thanks jbabey - that worked great once I spotted your slight typo at the end of the second line - I'm sure you threw it in on purpose to make sure I wasn't just copy-pasting! :)

Can I just ask you about `changeStatus(that)`? Why do you pass `that` to `changeStatus()`? It seems to work fine without it. I'm just interested to know. Thanks!

Comment: passing it is not necessary since the "that" variable is still in scope when in the changeStatus function. i will edit my answer to avoid confusion. what typo are you referring to on the second line?

Comment: Just a , instead of a ; - it didn't work until I sorted that.

Thanks for the link as well btw - haven't come across that site before.

Comment: you can declare multiple variables with one "var" keyword by comma separating them. not a typo.

Comment: Ha - might have known! You (I!) learn something everyday. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code to include the "changeStatus()" method's code directly in the callback closure to maintain the scope chain.

```
    var streams = $('article a[href^="http://65"]');
streams.addClass("offline");
streams.each(function (){
    destination = $(this).attr("href");
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=use%20%22store%3A%2F%2FtbYorcb2jIkiHPcRbkpSUG%22%20as%20HTTPStatus2%3B%20select%20status%20from%20HTTPStatus2%20where%20url%3D%22"+ encodeURIComponent(destination) +"%22&format=json&callback=",
        function(data){
            var httpstatus = data.query.results.result.status;
            if(httpstatus == 200){
                console.log('If = 200');
                console.log('changeStatus called');
                $(this).removeClass("offline").addClass("online");
            }
        }
    );

    //$(this).removeClass("offline").addClass("online");
});
```

Comment: Thanks John. I had started like this but found it didn't work...
If I add `console.log($(this));`it shows $(this) referring to the `get` request still.